# How to restore a not working Note 2 to factory

Tags: factory-reset

I have at hands a Note 2 that was rooted and Is now stuck to the Samsung logo. Backup is not available. Assuming something is wrong just at the software level, would be possible to bring it back to factory conditions? If this can be attempted, could you point me to some reliable sources?

Comment: Odin is the answer to flash stock recovery and get it back to factory state. But Note 2 comes in two versions. Be sure to check which version is yours and look up XDA. You will find plenty of guides

Comment: Thanks @beeshyams. Shall I embark on this or being stuck to the logo means that the motherboard is gone?

Comment: How valuable is this device to you? Sometimes you just have to put in the effort. Why try to talk yourself out of it; put in your best.

Comment: As @wbogacz said, go ahead. It doesn't mean mother board is dead.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will look for the necessary files.